# How can I extend my throttle cable by ~1"

Tags: motorcycle, throttle

The bracket that my right mirror screwed into broke off right near where it was welded to the handlebar, and I couldn't fix it so I just put a new mirror mount bracket to the right of it and moved my throttle slightly to the right to make space (and drilled a new hole on the bottom side of the handlebar where the pin goes into the handlebar to secure the throttle assembly).

But now my throttle cable is slightly short so it always stays on a little. How can I extend it by 1" or maybe a little less?

Is there something I can loosen that will make the throttle cable longer? Or is the cable usually the perfect length for the bike?

Comment: A photo would be helpful in terms of recommending fixes. There are "universal" cables available with a pre-molded stop on one end, which allows you to set it to length. But there may be a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving the new bracket to the left of the old one or grinding the old one off, which means you won’t have to mess around with a safety critical system...

If your “bodge” on your throttle cable fails halfway into a fast corner - what direction will you be taking?